# Как в запросе multi_query() вывести сообщение об отсутсвии данных в таблице по определенному запросу

Tags: php

пример мульти-запроса (Объектно-ориентированный стиль) из php.net https://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php

есть несколько строк с запросами:

```
$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5;";
$query .= "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE tag=0";
```

к примеру, по выборке в третьей строке никаких данных в бд нет.

проверка типа

```
$row=$result->fetch_row();
if(!$row[0]) echo 'данные отсутствуют';
```

ничего не дала, так как в `var_dump($row);` пусто.

На выходе должно получиться:
*my_user@localhost

-----------------

Нью-Йорк

Чикаго

-----------------

данные отсутствуют*

Как проверять и после чего ставить проверку в примере мульти-запроса на php.net?

Comment: Это одна строка с запросами

Comment: @Etki, да, одна строка, но запросы разделяются точкой с запятой, поэтому на выходе результат по каждому из запросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки наличия результата выборки в мульте запросе служит функция `bool mysqli_more_results ( mysqli $link )` [Подробнее...](https://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.more-results.php)

Проверка хорошо расписана в мануале по функции: `bool mysqli_multi_query ( mysqli $link , string $query )` [Подробнее...](https://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверка соединения */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5;";
$query .= "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE tag=0";

if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
  $i=0;
  do {
    /* получаем первый результирующий набор */
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            var_dump($row[0]);
            $i++;
        }
        $result->free();
    }

    if (!$mysqli->more_results() && $i==0) {
        echo 'данные отсутствуют';
    }

   } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* закрываем соединение */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Да, это срабатывает, но при этом сообщение "данные отсутствуют" выводится и в случае когда прежде были выбраны какие-то данные по запросу. То есть следует ожидать, что сообщение "данные отсутствуют" будет выводиться всегда, когда выборка достигнет конца. Необходимо произвести проверку и вывести сообщение об отсутствии данных только когда по запросу данных вообще никаких нет.

Answer (score 0):

Запрос

```
$query .= "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE tag=0";
```

Всегда возвращает строку, значение которой можно проверить

```
if($row[0] != 0) {
 // какие-то действия
} else {
 echo "данные отсутствуют";
}
```

А пусто в строке потому, что, вероятнее всего, запрос

```
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5;";
```

не дал никакого результата, в таком случае метод fetch_row() вернет NULL

Comment: вопрос в том, куда точно подставить проверку переменной $row в цикле do-while чтобы проверка срабатывала корректно по каждому из запросов которые передаются в multi_query(), либо каким образом реализовать проверку в цикле do-while с мультизапросом